# Reading Stream of data in Producer and push to Kafka Topic

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, message-queue, rpc, grpc

I want to read data from a **server** listening to stream of data in Producer and send to Topic.
The source of data is an **client-side streaming RPC** where the client writes a sequence of messages and sends them to the **server** using a provided stream.

I did found an [example](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-write-a-kafka-producer-using-twitter-stream) where Producer connects to a Twitter Client and reads data. However, my goal is to read the data as soon it comes on the **server listening to stream** in Producer and send to Kafka Topic.

Are there any examples similar or anyone has came across this scenario?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know the specifics of the streaming RPC mechanism you are using, but as first port of call I'd look to akka-stream-kafka (aka reactive-kafka) as it is tailored for specifically for streaming scenarios:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html

Check out the examples there. Also, alpakka is an initiative for integration patterns based on akka-stream but the list of connectors supported is so far somewhat limited:
http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/

Comment: Hi Michal, I am using gRPC(www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go.html) as RPC mechanism